# How to host several sites on one IP

Tags: networking, dns, webserver, hosts, hosting

I have a number of domains that I need to match on different websites. These websites are hosted on virtual machines that run on a dedicated server in the office where I work.

The connection with the outside is on a single network interface (the only public IP), that is that of the router. Network traffic management takes place on a server running Zentyal 6.2 located in a DMZ.

The goal would be to direct the various domains to the external IP and then make sure that they reach the VM with the corresponding site (each is configured with its fixed IP accessible to the LAN).

Here are the things I've already tried with no success:

- I redirected each domain on the IP specifying a port which I then forwarded to the corresponding VM (port forwarding). ex: 
  external_ip:15000 -> 10.1.1.1 (vm with site 1) 
  external_ip:16000 -> 10.1.1.2 (vm with site 2)
- I have configured the DNS of the domains on the external IP and I have made a port forwarding of all traffic to port 80 (or 443) of the VM; this solution is not good because I was unable to choose which VM to direct traffic to.
- I have configured the DNS of the domain as above but I have tried to use the Zentyal server as "local DNS server", it did not work but I don't know if because I have configured it wrong or simply because it is not a viable possibility.

The websites are of different nature (django sites, nextcloud, ...).
I have read about the possibility of using Apache VirtualHosts but I have no idea how to use them in my case.

Comment: You need an web server e.g. nginx (in one VM or on the host) that gets all the traffic and then based on the host name forwards the traffic to the correct VM. Typically the "external web server" also performs the HTTPS/TLS termination. If you are using HTTPS with client certs, this might be a problem.

Comment: Keyword: _reverse proxy_

Comment: I solved it by setting up a web proxy and apache virtualhost that takes care of making websites accessible and using zentyal's port forwarding for other services (e.g. mail). thanks everyone for the help